# Что делает класс Call в java?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, мобильная-разработка

При изучении retrofit столкнулся с такой строкой:

```
@GET("/users/{user}/repos")
Call<List<GitHubRepo>> reposForUser(@Path("user") String user);
```

Стал гуглить, но, при поиске информации про класс Call, по большей части, поисковик выдаёт информацию про класс Callable.

В общем, буду признателен, если расскажите, что это за класс и что он, в данной строке, делает

Comment: https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html

Comment: обычно Ctrl+Левая кнопка переводят туда, где этот класс описан

Comment: Это по сути сам вызов. Результата его можно дождаться синхронно (запустив его через execute), либо получить результат асинхронно, когда он выполнится - через колбэк (колбэк можно передать через метод enqueue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По сути интерфейс `Call` это часть реализации шаблона [Команда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)). Т.е. `Call` содержит в себе все необходимые параметры для выполнения запроса.

Используя объект типа `Call` можно выполнить запрос синхронно (метод `execute`) или асинхронно (`enqueue`), либо сохранить этот объект и выполнить запрос позже.

Это часть библиотеки retrofit2, т.е. он не входит в стандартную библиотеку java.

Comment: Да, только это интерфейс, а не класс

Comment: Да, действительно, поправил.